# Generating Authentication token for SLACK using postman

Tags: java, postman, token, slack-api

I want to access slack APIs which need authentication token. How can I generate Auth token through postman and then use that token to access other slack APIs to post messages to slack channels?

Later I want to access it using JAVA Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach for getting an API token is to create a [Slack app](https://api.slack.com/start/overview) and [install that Slack app into your workspace](https://api.slack.com/start/overview#installing_distributing).

In the Slack app you can choose the OAuth scopes, which will define what your API token / app is allowed to do. e.g. to post messages to a channel you can use the scope `chat:write:user`.

Note that you do not need Postman to create the API token. Just create the Slack app and click on "Install app" / "Install to workspace" on the app management page.

Comment: Thank you Erik !!. It did help